# Checking if two yacc grammars are equivalent

Tags: parsing, complexity-theory

You've written a yacc grammar (or some other LALR grammar in the tool of your choice), and you've decided that you want to refactor some productions for efficiency, clarity, whatever. For example, you had:

```
xs : xs ';' x
   | xs ';'
   | x
```

You want to make it more obvious that there can be multiple semicolons, so you rewrite it as:

```
semi_plus : semi_plus ';'
          | ';'
xs : xs semi_plus x
   | x
```

OK, so, looks plausible... but did I actually do the refactoring correctly? It would be great if I could pass these declarations to a tool that would tell me if the grammars are equivalent or not. (For now, let us consider solely the question of whether or not we recognize the same languages.)

One knee-jerk reaction is to quote that context free grammar equivalence is undecidable. In fact, even the problem of determining if a CFG is regular [is undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach%27s_theorem#Applications). But yacc does not recognize CFGs: it recognizes deterministic context free grammars, and for these, it is known that [equivalence is decidable](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/cps/india.pdf). But has anyone implemented any of these decision procedures?

Comment: The link you provide with text "equivalence is decidable" does not, in fact, provide any references relevant to that question. Indeed, when Hopcroft and Ullman wrote their magnificent text, it was not yet known whether equivalence of two DCFLs is decidable. That fact was not proven until 1997, and afaik it is still not known whether or not there is a polynomial time algorithm. You appear to be confusing regularity with DCFLs, in some way: equivalence of DFAs is straightforward (and the algo is in H&U iirc) but a DCFL might not be regular.

Comment: Thank you for the fix rici; I *did* read somewhere that DCFL/DPDA equivalence was decidable but I must have pasted in the wrong link. The link is fixed now (I've decided to link straight to Stirling's proof, on the recommendation of Bob Atkey)